# How to move 8 different images together in spritekit

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have 8 square images i.e 8 skpritenodes, which i want to rotate from left to right of the screen. Each node is placed one after another in x axis. i want to move them together on X-axis.

How should i approach this situation.

Please give me some small example to add nodes to array and move that array completely using skaction.

Comment: add them all to the same parent node, move the parent node

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks for the answer. But i have a new problem..I have a Sprite node with many 6 child nodes. Each are placed one after another in X-axis.
I want to know the complete with of the Sksprite node.

    SKSpriteNode *array = [SKSpriteNode node];

    [array addChild:box1];
    [array addChild:box2];
    [array addChild:box3];
    [array addChild:box4];
    [array addChild:box5];
    [array addChild:box6];

array.size.width dosen't get me any size, so how should i get the complete width of array with child nodes..

Comment: there's a method for that, check sknode class reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create an action

```
SKAction *move = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(10,0) duration:0.1];
```

Next apply said action to the nodes. Store them in the array.

```
for (SKNode *node in self.array) {
    [node runAction:move];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But i have a new problem, how can i get the complete width of an SKSpriteNode with multiple child nodes..And also how can i get complete width of an array having multiple nodes..

Comment: @user2897282 You may iterate over the array and remember lowest X position of a sprite and then (highest X position + width of sprite) - this will be your sprite length